# preselected custom fields in custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I have a custom post type called "stock" and each post is going to have a stock_id, stock_name, stock_description and stock_available fields,...I would like to have defaults for these fields so the user doesn't have to load them on each new item. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do that would be to use [**Verve Meta Boxes**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/verve-meta-boxes/) plugin which lets you define a metabox with a simple UI (**no code is needed**) and you have an options to set the default value for each field.

Comment: and is there a way to set these meta boxes to show up only on custom post types?

Comment: If i recall there is an option to set the post type

Comment: I've been having lots of troubles getting these values the way explains so( eg `get_post_custom_values('stock_id');`) any clues on how to debug/figure this out?

Comment: Simply get them using get_post_Meta http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

Answer (score 0):

Two angles of approach:
1) More user friendly: would be to make a meta box for these custom fields. Your meta box for these custom fields would contain the `<input />` elements - you can then put a default value in these, which when the post is saved will be stored.

See [add_meta_box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) for more information.

2) At minimum, you can hook onto the 'save_post' action, and check if there's a value, and if not store that as the meta value:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'myplugin_save_postdata' );

function myplugin_save_postdata($post_id)
{
  // verify if this is an auto save routine. 
  // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
  if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
      return;

  // Check permissions
  if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) 
  {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
        return;
  }
  else
  {
     if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return;
  }

  // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data

  $mydata = $_POST['myplugin_new_field'];

  if (!$mydata)
  {
    // add default value
    $mydata = 'a default value;
  }

  // save the data
  update_post_meta($post_id, 'my_meta_field', $mydata);

  return $mydata;
}
```

Comment: may I ask you how you'd have a <select> with "yes" or "no" answers there? I'm trying to do something like this but it doesn't work: `function stock_available() {
    global $post;
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="stockmeta_noncename" id="stockmeta_noncename" value="' .
    wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';
 
    
    $location = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_available', true);
 
    // Echo out the field
    echo '<option><select name="_available" value="yes">SI</select><select name="_nonavailable" value="no">NO</select></option>';
 
}`